# Ng2 <Component> is not a known element

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have browsed the other similar posts on stackoverflow, but have not found one that helps my cause, so here goes:

I am using angular2 based on the webpack "boiler-plate" from angular.io and included the routing bit.

I end up with this error even though the current setup is extremely minimal:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'Mathador' is not a known element:
1. If 'Mathador' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
...
```

Here are the relevant code fragments

**app/app.html**

```
    <main>
        <h1>Mathador prototype</h1>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>

**app/app.routes.ts**

    import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HomeComponent }        from './pages/home/home'


    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', component: HomeComponent
        }
    ];

    export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);



**app/app.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import '../../public/css/styles.css';

    @Component({
        selector    : 'my-app',
        templateUrl : './app.html',
        styleUrls   : ['./app.scss']
    })

    export class AppComponent {

    }



**app/app.module.ts**

    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { routing }       from './app.routes';

    // core
    import { AppComponent }  from './app';

    // pages
    import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home';

    // components
    import { Mathador } from './components/mathador/mathador';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            routing
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            Mathador
        ],
        bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })

    export class AppModule { }


**app/pages/home/home.ts**

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector    : 'my-home',
        templateUrl : './home.html',
        styleUrls   : ['./home.scss']
    })
    export class HomeComponent {

        constructor() {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

**app/pages/home/home.html**

    <h1>home!</h1>

    <Mathador></Mathador>

**app/components/mathador.html**

    <div>transclusion succesfull!</div>

**app/components/mathador.ts**

    // Importing core components
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector    : 'mathador',
        templateUrl : './mathador.html' 
    })

    export class Mathador  {
        constructor() { }
    }
```

Comment: What **is** `Matador`?

Comment: `selector : 'mathador',` lowercase

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer mathador is my custom editor (or atleast.. tobe)

Comment: So is it an Angular2 component?

Comment: @yurzui I am fully rebuilding this code from a meteor project in a webpack project with tons of stuff migrated.. can't believe I missed something this simple.. thanks :)

Comment: If you've answered your question, would you add the answer as an answer, rather than just as a comment?